# Is the self realized only by sanyasis?

Tags: marriage, sanyasi, grihastha

Can a person attain self realization while living in grihastha ashram and doing worldy activities(doing a job)?

For eg:- For doing wordly activities one requires to be turn outwards whereas to contemplate on aatma one requires to turn inwards?

So can a person desiring self realization devote half of his time to wordly activities and half to meditate on aatma attain self realization?

If yes then how?

Comment: If you look back in history most of the revered & self realized rishis were married so a person can attain self realization while living in grihastha ashram

Answer (score 1):

From the standpoint of Bhagavad Gita,

Lord Krishna persistently advocates Karma Phala Thyaga(Karma yoga) and not Karma Thyaga(deriliction of duty) for Arjuna(Grihastha)(in and through the Bhagavad Gita ), from the outset ,  which sets the context for the treatise.

Bhagavad Gita 5.2

> śhrī bhagavān uvācha
> sannyāsaḥ karma-yogaśh cha niḥśhreyasa-karāvubhau
> tayos tu karma-sannyāsāt karma-yogo viśhiṣhyate

> The Supreme Lord said: Both the path of karm sanyās (renunciation of actions) and karm yog (renunciation of the fruits of action) lead to the supreme goal. But karm yog is superior to karm sanyās.

Having renounced various duties required to uphold one's own family
and the welfare of common good,

if one does not possess the worth of mind to progress spiritually, it leads to hypocrisy, as against a Brahma Nishta, who takes up Sanyas.

Bhagavad Gita 5.6

> sannyāsas tu mahā-bāho duḥkham āptum ayogataḥ
> yoga-yukto munir brahma na chireṇādhigachchhati

> Perfect renunciation (karm sanyās) is difficult to attain without performing karm yog, O mighty-armed Arjun, but the sage who is adept in karm yog quickly attains the Supreme.(English Translation by Swami Mukundananda)

Bhagavad Gita 5.8,5.9 details the culmination of karmayoga(Pride of ownership naturally fades away)

> Those steadfast in karm yog, always think, “I am not the doer,” even while engaged in seeing, hearing, touching, smelling, moving, sleeping, breathing, speaking, excreting, grasping, and opening or closing the eyes. With the light of divine knowledge, they see that it is only the material senses that are moving amongst their objects.(English Translation by Swami Mukundananda)

Bhagavad Gita 18.2

> śhrī-bhagavān uvācha
> kāmyānāṁ karmaṇāṁ nyāsaṁ sannyāsaṁ kavayo viduḥ
> sarva-karma-phala-tyāgaṁ prāhus tyāgaṁ vichakṣhaṇāḥ

> The Supreme Divine Personality said: Giving up of actions motivated by desire is what the wise understand as sanyās. Relinquishing the fruits of all actions is what the learned declare to be tyāg.(English Translation by Swami Mukundananda)

Bhagavad Gita 18.7

> niyatasya tu sannyāsaḥ karmaṇo nopapadyate
> mohāt tasya parityāgas tāmasaḥ parikīrtitaḥ

> Prescribed duties should never be renounced. Such deluded renunciation is said to be in the mode of ignorance.(English Translation by Swami Mukundananda)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Try meditation. Try Gnana Yoga. Understand yourself better...how bad & good are you? Always be aware that someone watches all your activites. Keep a neutral stance on life & death. Live each moment by 100% being in the zone. Be ready to give away the results of your hard-work...yes sacrifice. There are thousands of books. Janaka(Seetha's dad) was a self-realized person, a king as well. Yagnyavalkya had two wives..Maitreyi & Katyayini..received Shukla Yajur veda from Sun while being in active life, went off to forest. His conversations form part of Brihadarnyaka Upanisad.
May be this link might help..
https://www.tamilbrahmins.com/threads/a-controversial-thirumoolar-verse.42340/